# regular expression character class with grep comamnd

Tags: regex, grep

I am learning regular expression past few days. i used to character class [] for range of selection only alpha characters in lower case only.

For example: file contain text like below:

```
$ cat file
.a
.b
.c .d
```

Using grep command i am trying to match (line starts with dot) lower case alphabetic characters using below command

```
$ grep '^\.[a-z]' file
```

this will matching characters only
             .a
             .b
             .c 
Here my question? why grep command not matching **.d** in the same line **.c**

I tried to match .d using this command also:

```
$ grep '^\.[a-z][a-z]` file
```

But this one does not work can you please some one help me to this one ? and what is the difference between these two character class

```
[a-z] vs [a-z][a-z]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match all of them, then remove `^`, doing:

```
grep '\.[a-z]' file
```

The `^` means that it must be at the start of a line. So you're trying to match a literal dot, followed by a character in the range of a and z. Which must be at the start of a line.

The difference between `[a-z]` and `[a-z][a-z]` is thereby that `[a-z]` matches a single character in the range of `a-z`. Doing `[a-z][a-z]` means that you're doing it twice. Thus trying to match 2 sequential characters both in the range of `a-z`.

**[Here's a live example of the modified version](https://regex101.com/r/5LS0Ju/1)**

<sup>I highly recommend using regex101.com (which the example above uses), if you're trying to learn regex. As it gives a nice explanation of the regex you entered.</sup>

Comment: Hi Vallentin Thanks lot your solution was perfectly good to learn regex.

Comment: You're welcome! Do try to use regex101.com when trying to learn regex, it really is helpful!

Comment: It's very amazing tool for beginners i am very happy today cool :)

Comment: If you don't mind can you please give me one example about this [a-z][a-z]?

Comment: [As you can see here, it only matches when there's 2 characters after each other](https://regex101.com/r/oH07oE/1)

Comment: Thanks lot Again Have a nice Day :)